# is it possible to change a document name dynamically - Doc lib is in WSS v3

Tags: 2007

If i'm not wrong a document is unique to each doc library.
What i want to do is use some fields the users select to make up a document name.e.g
docname_Created
I'm sure i can do this via Object Model but can i use a SPD workflow for this?
Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd either need to write an event receiver in visual studio or use a third party product [as described in this example](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/sharepoint-workflow-power-pack-user.html) in combination with SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Muhmbi i tried using the SPD workflow to replace the file name but no luck.I reacko the event reciever would be the way to go but haven't got that to work yet

Answer (score 1):

You're much better off populating some metadata fields than cobbling together some sort of compound filename. You'll just be replicating the poor practice of overloading the filename with significant data that can't ever really be teased out reliably.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Title column that you could use to write your name to.  I would opt for a Calculated Column myself and expose that in the view.  Is there a reason you need the Name column to be updated?

Comment: iOnline247 thnks for the response.The reason why i need it is users would need to  upload one document twice whereas you can't do that because it overrides the original.They are doing this because when they upload the docs they select a different category to move it to.So it has to me unique to each category.
Hope you understand my pain

Comment: The document just needs to be categorized differently?  What's the reasoning behind the same document being uploaded to the same document library multiple times?  Why not modify the document in/on SP and update accordingly?

I think I'm missing some of the process and that would help to have some of this to help you better.

Comment: iOnline247 good question re why doc need to be uploaded twice.Well the reason is when users upload and try to move a doc to multiple categories and the categories are too many the get a prompt stating it can't be more than 250 characters:(
Hope you understand my pain now:) No idea how to increase the no: of characters to be over 250 when using a multi value field?